# Retrieve columns from pg_stat_all_indexes

Tags: postgresql

Given the following query:

```sql
SELECT pg_get_indexdef(indexrelid)
FROM pg_stat_all_indexes
WHERE schemaname = 'public'
```

I get all of the indexes that exist in the public schema. The question is if there's a way for me to query the columns that are indexed. For example, given the following table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE caregiver
(
    id         INTEGER PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    ssn        TEXT,

    UNIQUE (ssn)
);
```

I get the following index (`pg_get_indexdef(indexrelid)`):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX caregiver_ssn_key ON public.caregiver USING btree (ssn)
```

Which I would like to return in the query the `ssn`.

If there's an index that is a constraint of two or more columns, then I would like to get all of them. For example:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_name ON public.caregiver_agency_assoc USING btree (agency_id, caregiver_id)
```

I would like to receive `agency_id` and `caregiver_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to query the system catalogs:

```
SELECT d.objid::regclass AS index_name,
       a.attname AS column_name,
       d.refobjid::regclass AS table_name
FROM pg_class AS c
   JOIN pg_depend AS d
      ON c.oid = d.refobjid
   JOIN pg_attribute AS a
      ON d.refobjid = a.attrelid
         AND d.refobjsubid = a.attnum
WHERE d.refclassid = 'pg_class'::regclass
  AND d.classid = 'pg_class'::regclass
  AND c.relnamespace = 'public'::regnamespace
ORDER BY d.refobjid, d.objid;
```

This will return all indexes in the schema, with the corresponding tables and the columns that occur in their definition.

Comment: Looks like exactly what I need. Although, is it possible to retrieve only the unique indexes? sorry for not mentioning that in the question.

Comment: Sure. Join with `pg_index`, that has an attribute for that.